# Pulling data from Netflix through private account

Tags: authentication, curl, session-cookies, wget, netflix

I want to pull a list of all the movies and shows I have seen on Netflix for a personal project, which Netflix has a page for.

Results from trying curl:

```
curl https://www.netflix.com/MoviesYouveSeen -v
*   Trying 50.112.92.119...
* Connected to www.netflix.com (50.112.92.119) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* ALPN/NPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* SSL connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* Server certificate:
*   subject: CN=www.netflix.com,OU=Operations,O="Netflix, Inc.",L=Los Gatos,ST=CALIFORNIA,C=US
*   start date: Apr 14 00:00:00 2015 GMT
*   expire date: Apr 12 23:59:59 2017 GMT
*   common name: www.netflix.com
*   issuer: CN=Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4,OU=Symantec Trust Network,O=Symantec Corporation,C=US
> GET /MoviesYouveSeen HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.netflix.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
< Date: Tue, 26 Apr 2016 14:47:16 GMT
< Edge-Control: no-cache, no-store
< location: https://www.netflix.com/Login?nextpage=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.netflix.com%2FMoviesYouveSeen
< req_id: 2a134cc9-7f77-4a35-9d83-0099fc7a2466
< Server: shakti-prod i-8cf6164a
< Set-Cookie: nflx-rgn=uw2|1461682036196; Max-Age=-1; Expires=Tue, 26 Apr 2016 14:47:15 GMT; Path=/; Domain=.netflix.com
< Set-Cookie: memclid=b40d0e2c-27b3-4d72-9b14-4477fcf5fa39; Max-Age=31536000; Expires=Wed, 26 Apr 2017 14:47:16 GMT; Path=/; Domain=.netflix.com
< Set-Cookie: nfvdid=BQFmAAEBEDgFjrzXIIi7X6rTj6vmSYUwYpekhXXCCx5ywGWHaOvo0%2BmNx86oMCsliwERTTbRi6FwmgZM3YhqFUBfffSwJ0Kd; Max-Age=31536000; Expires=Wed, 26 Apr 2017 14:47:16 GMT; Path=/; Domain=.netflix.com
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536
< Via: 1.1 i-6af8eaad (us-west-2)
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< X-Netflix-From-Zuul: true
< X-Netflix.nfstatus: 1_1
< X-Originating-URL: https://www.netflix.com/MoviesYouveSeen
< X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block; report=https://ichnaea.netflix.com/log/freeform/xssreport
< Content-Length: 256
< Connection: keep-alive
< 
* Connection #0 to host www.netflix.com left intact
```

I also tried wget:

```
wget https://www.netflix.com/MoviesYouveSeen
--2016-04-26 10:57:23--  https://www.netflix.com/MoviesYouveSeen
Resolving www.netflix.com (www.netflix.com)... 54.244.126.7, 50.112.115.177, 54.214.7.82, ...
Connecting to www.netflix.com (www.netflix.com)|54.244.126.7|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Syntax error in Set-Cookie: nflx-rgn=uw2|1461682643973; Max-Age=-1; Expires=Tue, 26 Apr 2016 14:57:23 GMT; Path=/; Domain=.netflix.com at position 39.
Location: https://www.netflix.com/Login?nextpage=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.netflix.com%2FMoviesYouveSeen [following]
--2016-04-26 10:57:24--  https://www.netflix.com/Login?nextpage=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.netflix.com%2FMoviesYouveSeen
Reusing existing connection to www.netflix.com:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Syntax error in Set-Cookie: nflx-rgn=uw2|1461682644112; Max-Age=-1; Expires=Tue, 26 Apr 2016 14:57:23 GMT; Path=/; Domain=.netflix.com at position 39.
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘MoviesYouveSeen’

MoviesYouveSeen                        [ <=>                                                             ]  41.63K   220KB/s    in 0.2s    

2016-04-26 10:57:24 (220 KB/s) - ‘MoviesYouveSeen’ saved [42629]
```

It looks like I am not being properly authenticated. Inside my browser if I view source I can see the list of movies. Any suggestions for getting the data?

Answer (score 0):

That 302 response is redirecting you to the login page. You'd need to be logged in for the query to work correctly.